# Windows 7 - Assigning hotkeys to applications

Tags: windows-7, windows

I'm on windows 7 and was hoping to find an application that would make it easy to assign hotkeys to applications, for example I might assign ALT+C as the command to bring my Chrome window to the front (or open a new instance if I don't have Chrome open).

I was wondering if anyone can recommend an application that does this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows can do this without any addons!

Simply right click on a shortcut to an application, then go to the `Shortcut key` field, and type what you want to launch.

Unfortunately, you can only set hotkeys with two or all three modifier keys (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>,<kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>).

[image]

If you only want one, you can use [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) to set a script to do this.

Comment: I'd need to retry but on previous versions that opened a new window, it didn't maximise any existing ones. For example if I assigned CTRL+ALT+F to Firefox and I have Firefox open I want it to maximise it. I've seen some software that seems to do that sort of thing but was hoping for a recommendation.

Comment: Then you really need Auto Hot Key, it will do this without problems! Windows Shortcut Key will do the same as clicking the icon, which is, launch a new window.

Comment: Ahh cool, I did find auto hotkey but hadn't got to given it a try. Will do so thanks very much.

Comment: *Unfortunately, you can only set hotkeys with two or all three modifier keys* – could you please provide reference for this?

Comment: *Windows Shortcut Key will do the same as clicking the icon, which is, launch a new window.* – actually it will run executable and it is up to this executable what happens next.