# How do you disable the F1 key for whole system?

Tags: windows

Is there a way to temporarily disable the F1 key?

I do not want to permanently disable it, but perhaps a toggle switch so that I can enable it for certain actions.

The problem is I'm trying to solve is that I have never intentionally pressed the F1 key, but occasionally press it accidentally (which can be a pain because most help systems use F1 to activate).

Comment: You can always just disable the Windows Help service, or you want to disable help in programs as well? Assigning `F1` to help is convention, not law. What about programs that use it for something else? What about combos (e.g., `Shift+F1`, `Ctrl+Alt+F1`)? Many programs use such combos for special purposes; do you want those disabled as well?

Comment: @Synetech I have updated my question to be a bit clearer. To clarify, I would like to disable the key. So if the combo uses that key, it cannot be performed.

Answer (score 11):

The simplest solution: use this [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/) macro

```
f1::Return
```

would do just that.

You can disable it by closing the application in the system tray, and renable by opening it again.

Comment: Note: this would prevent it from working in a game as well. You would have to either quit the script before running the game and re-run it after, or add some sort of game-detection-and-exclusion to it.

Comment: In the current version of the program, I think you can right-click on the notification area (formerly known as *System Tray*) icon and click *Suspend Hotkeys* to toggle the functionality.

Comment: I would recommend using the registry key solution instead (as mentioned in this topic). It only changes the help button, nothing else.

Comment: it should have another alternative like ctrl+F1 sends F1 in case you actually want it

Answer (score 6):

On Windows 7-10 (maybe also lower versions?) **to disable** the F1 button in all programs (just for the currently logged in user), save this file as `disable.reg` and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win32]
@=""

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}\1.0\0\win64]
@=""
```

**Or** open `regedit`, browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib`, create a Key (folder) named `{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}`, then create a Key inside that named `1.0`, then create a Key inside that named `0`, then create 2 Keys inside that named `win32` and `win64`. Open each of the `winXX` Keys, double click `(Default)` and then press <kbd>OK</kbd>. Observe that the `Data` has changed from `(value not set)` to be blank.

---

**To re-enable** the F1 key, save this file as `enable.reg` and run it:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[-HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib\{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}]
```

**Or** open `regedit`, browse to `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Classes\Typelib` and delete the folder named `{8cec5860-07a1-11d9-b15e-000d56bfe6ee}`

Comment: I tried this on Windows 7, and it works perfectly. You don't even need to restart, it's immediately effective.

Comment: What exactly does this do? A quick explanation would be nice. Does it disable the F1 key completely or is this just for the Windows help? Do I roll it back by just removing the key again? I don‘t want to run this without knowing what it does. An extension of your answer would be appreciated :)

Comment: @bugybunny It might be 2 years later but I've done that for you :)

Answer (score 3):

With [Sharpkeys](http://sharpkeys.codeplex.com/), you can disable or remap most keyboard keys. To use it to disable the F1 key:

1. Open the program.
2. Click *Add*.
3. Under the left panel, click *Type Key* and press **F1** on the keyboard.
4. In the right panel, select *Turn Key Off*.
5. Click *OK*.
6. Click *Write to Registry*.
7. Log off or restart the computer.
8. To restore the original state, delete the entry and repeat the previous 2 steps.

[image: Mapping "F1" to "Turn Key Off" in SharpKeys]

Comment: Note that this method requires the user to log off or restart the computer for the changes to take effect. Because of this, it doesn't allow the F1 to be conveniently re-enabled as needed.

Comment: This also blocks key combinations that use F1.

Comment: I do not recommend this. For example, if a game uses F1 button, you cant press it anymore. Just noticed it. VERY BAD!!!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to completely deactivate the key (so that even the Chrome help doesn't open or whatever program uses it), you can remap the key to nothing. The downside is that it's disabled for the whole system and any program that might use it for something else, you can not map any action in a program to it anymore. It's as if you removed the physical key (except that it's easier to revert).

You have to change a registry key like in this tutorial: https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/ ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180401070831/https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/disable-caps-lock-key-in-windows-vista/))

The actual key number for F1 was hard to find, but this table should have it: http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il/~microlab/MicroLab/Labs/ScanCodes.htm ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20171017102513/http://www.ee.bgu.ac.il:80/~microlab/MicroLab/Labs/ScanCodes.htm))

Otherwise this table has a lot of other formats: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374(v=vs.60).aspx ([archive](http://web.archive.org/web/20180102155300/https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa299374%28v=vs.60%29.aspx))

And if even that doesn't work, you can install a program from here to get the code: [Where to find windows keyboard scancode registry information?](https://superuser.com/questions/550679/where-to-find-windows-keyboard-scancode-registry-information)

To get a toggle, you have to first export the key without changes and call it "F1 on" or whatever and after you made the changes, export it again and call it "F1 off" or whatever. The problem with this is that whenever you change something in that key, you have to export it again or you would revert that change the next time you open the file.

Comment: It works! These code remap F1 to nothing.

`reg.exe add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Keyboard Layout" /f /t REG_BINARY /v "Scancode Map" /d 00000000000000000200000000003B0000000000`

Answer (score 1):

Other answers have addressed how to *disable* the F1 key. I will address the *underlying* problem:

> I have never intentionally pressed the F1 key, but occasionally press it accidentally (which can be a pain because most help systems use F1 to activate).

Back when I used Windows, I had the same complaint. Rather than attempt to disable it, my approach was to **assign F1 as a hotkey to run a shortcut** to a frequently used program. Since I am *intentionally* using it, I am less likely to accidentally hit it because I have a better sense of where it is located. Even if I were to accidentally press it, it would just run a program I'm likely to need soon anyway.

See [Windows 7 - Assigning hotkeys to applications](https://superuser.com/q/332436/903157)

[image]

Comment: Awesome solution, far more OS friendly than many others offered here. This also works in Windows 10. And I now have a key to open the command prompt! Cheers

Comment: @JonathanBarton I also assigned the key to open a command prompt.

Answer (score 0):

Follow the below steps,

- Create a restore point.
- start > run > regedit
- search for this registry key:

  > HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\App Paths\HELPCTR.EXE
- Double click on Default and change the path to any dummy executable that does nothing.
- Click ok and restart.

You can find dummy.exe here:

http://www.ehow.com/how_8053450_disable-f1-windows-xp.html

Comment: I really don’t like this—why exactly did they choose `svchost` to replace it with? At one time I had disabled the Windows help function by replacing `helpctr.exe` with a small program that does nothing. That worked just fine but of course has issues. This is somewhat similar and has similar, if different issues. A much simpler and safer solution (the one I use now), is to simply disable the Windows Help service. Of course this is all moot here because he wants to disable the key altogether, not just Windows Help. But, for others who land here trying to turn off Help, just disable the service.

Comment: This is the best method IMO, but instead, you should run some empty executable instead.