# Can I configure my Windows key to act like an Fn key?

Tags: windows-10, keyboard, keymap, fn-key, windows-key

I've always hated the <kbd>Fn</kbd> keys.  Give me dedicated <kbd>Home</kbd>/<kbd>End</kbd>/<kbd>PgUp</kbd>/<kbd>PgDn</kbd>keys any day.  But then I got a new laptop (XPS 13), and used it almost exclusively for six months.

Now I go back to my desktop, and I'm unable to code in it without constantly hitting <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd>, etc., etc.  Which does nothing useful, other than to move windows to one side of the monitor, etc.

Is there something I can do to re-map <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>up</kbd> to <kbd>PgUp</kbd>, <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>left</kbd> to <kbd>Home</kbd>, etc.?

Comment: `fn` keys are usually hardware-controlled. This means that your keyboard never sends the `fn` key to your OS but rather handles it itself. There is no way to remap it.

Comment: My first requirement for any laptops is a dedicated Home/End/PageUp/PageDown at the proper position, although recently I've lowered it down to having a keypad so that I can use those keys on the numpad instead of the stupid arrow keys. Actually Win+arrow keys are quite useful when you need to open/compare 2 windows at once.

Answer (score 1):

Fn keys can't be remapped, because they do not send scancodes like all other keys which can be picked up by Windows or other applications. Instead, it comes directly from the BIOS.

With the Microsoft [Surface Pro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_Pro), you can toggle your 'F' keys to be always on by pressing <kbd>Fn</kbd> + [Caps Lock](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caps_Lock). This means you can just press <kbd>F1</kbd> without having to press <kbd>Fn</kbd> at all.

Double check your computer model against the user manual and see if such feature exists. You might get some luck with a toggle function existing for your machine.

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Use [The Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/bb964665.aspx).</strike>

After reading more about this, key to key mapping is done in the Windows registry. Check these links:

- [Where to find windows keyboard scancode registry information?](https://superuser.com/questions/550679/where-to-find-windows-keyboard-scancode-registry-information)
- https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/216893
- http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/6/1/161ba512-40e2-4cc9-843a-923143f3456c/scancode.doc

Like @GiantTree mentioned, I don't think you can remap `Fn` + `Key` to a certain key. Sorry I don't have more time to test these out.

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't even show the windows key in its layout, and all the other "similar" keys (ctrl,alt,shift,tab,caps,return,backspace) are marked as "unassignable", so even if the windows key was shown I'm not convinced it'd let me do much with it.  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I'll update the post.