# Autohotkey disable Fn+Win key

Tags: windows, windows-10, autohotkey, start-menu

Here's the script to disable windows start menu, but allow modifiers, it works as intended:

```
LWin & vk07::return
LWin::return
```

I want to disable Fn+Win key, because it's opening windows start menu.

Comment: which laptop are you using? [Fn isn't typically a key that generates a scancode](https://superuser.com/q/1042896/241386), except on Macs, so only the keyboard controller knows what was pressed

Comment: Dell inspiron 7577

Comment: [Windows/Start Key Requires FN](https://www.dell.com/community/Laptops-General-Read-Only/Windows-Start-Key-Requires-FN/td-p/5161713)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer depends on your keyboard and computer.

If you suspect that the combination <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>Fn</kbd> generates a special
key, you may find out what this key is by using the procedure described in the
AutoHotKey article
[Special Keys](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/KeyList.htm#SpecialKeys).

Another method for tracking what that key-combination is doing, is by right-click on
a running AutoHotKey script in the tray-bar and choosing "Windows Spy".

Comment: Thanks for the tip, it turns out to be `RWin` if i use Fn+Windows key.