# 2 different keys type the same letter

Tags: keyboard, keyboard-shortcuts, keyboard-layout, button-remapping, symbols

Recently I got a new keyboard with ISO layout and Spanish distribution.

The problem is that one key does the same function as another different key
as seen on the image, those 2 keys should type different symbols, but both type "ç"

[image: screenshot]

There is no problem with the one on the right (since it's the actual key that should type the symbol), but the one on the left should type the "<>" symbols.

I have tried uninstalling the keyboard drivers and restarting my PC, but it didn't work.

Also I tried changing my keyboard language distribution, but also didn't work.

I tried remapping the left key too, but both keys got remapped (and so the right one, that should type "ç", was typing "<>").

Comment: Try to add more information, like what OS are you using, keyboard model, and such.

Answer (score 0):

I would try to check what scan codes the keyboard reports for those two keys. Those scan codes are then converted to input keys (e.g. <kbd><</kbd>), based on your keyboard layout. The tool [Sharpkeys](https://superuser.com/a/550857) is able to display the scan codes. You can [download](https://github.com/randyrants/sharpkeys/releases) the portable zip version and open "Add/Type key" window. It will you the scan code.

[image]

If the scan code is the same for both keys, you might have a hardware issue. If they are different, you might have a keyboard layout incompatability. I bought a US layout 87-key keyboard, but wanted to use it with a European 88-key layout. So I replaced the <kbd>§</kbd> key with the <kbd><</kbd>,<kbd>></kbd> key, which I actully need. Assuming you are using windows, You can use the [Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=102134) utility to create your own custom layout.