# Map left backslash key only in US ISO keyboard

Tags: windows, keyboard, keyboard-layout, autohotkey, windows-11

I am used to working with the US ANSI keyboard but right now, I am stuck with the US ISO keyboard since ANSI is unavailable for my new laptop.

It has two backslash keys and the left shift key is split into half-width. So, I want to map the left backslash key into the left shift key to restore the previous layout.

How do I do that? I would prefer OS-level solutions rather than AutoHotkey since OS-level solutions are more robust and rarely have glitches.

[image]

Comment: How do you get two backslash keys? ISO moves it from above return to left of Z by default. https://i.stack.imgur.com/n07Hn.jpg What language & keyboard type do you have set in prefs?

Comment: MSKLC (Microsoft Keyboard Layout Creator) would be one option, then there is also [Keyboard Manager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/powertoys/keyboard-manager) from PowerToys which seems to be based on keyboard hooks. Last but not least there is the [registry method](https://www.technewstoday.com/how-to-remap-keyboard-keys/) (also [here](https://superuser.com/a/1454198)) method which allows to re-map individual keys by scan code. Since you tagged [tag:autohotkey] I reckon you can tap into its hooking facilities to achieve the same effect without the PowerToys.

Comment: you can use [SharpKeys](https://www.randyrants.com/category/sharpkeys/) which modifies the key map so there'll be no runtime overhead. Another tool is [Microsoft PowerToys](https://www.howtogeek.com/710290/how-to-remap-any-key-or-shortcut-on-windows-10/) which has more features

Comment: @Tetsujin See the attached screenshot in my post. First keyboard in the screenshot was my previous keyboard. Second keyboard in screenshot is my new keyboard.

Comment: Yes… but it's not marked with the keys you are referring to, whereas my image is. One backslash, position changes depending on ANSI or ISO. On ISO, it's already been moved to between Z & Shift.

Comment: @phuclv Powertoys was not able to identify both slash key individually (it was over-writting both). But Sharpkeys does the job. Thanks

Comment: @0xC0000022L Shapkeys did the job for me